# Pinch-to-zoom on only some pages

Tags: html, mobile, zooming

Is it possible to make a mobile website have pinch to zoom capabilities on some pages but not other, for example not on the home page, but on a page with a image on it? I want people to be able to zoom into images but I don't want them to zoom on other pages because the text gets really little or really big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's good practice to let users decide if text is too large or small.

But, if you do want to control it, use the viewport meta-tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
```

Keeping initial-scale and maximum-scale the same, or by setting user-scalable to no, will let you keep the user from zooming.  Set user-scalable to yes and adjust the initial-scale and the maximum scale to set how zoomed in the page starts, and how far the user can zoom in to.

See:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying.html#toc-meta-viewport